# How are custom hooks related to the component using them?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I will argue about the core hook `useState` but I guess it applies the same for custom hooks. Consider this small ReactJS piece of code implementing a simple counter:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Counter = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Counter value: {counter}</h1>

            <button onClick={() => { setCounter(counter + 1); }}>Increment</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default Counter;
```

When the button is clicked the counter gets updated and it's new value is shown nicely.

I guess `setCounter` is a closure inside de `useState` function, and when the button is clicked, that closure is called and the `counter` attribute is updated inside `useState` internals.

But how does `useState` knows that it's "hosting" `Counter` component needs to be rendered again?. No relationship or reference between them is apparently established in the code.

Thanks

Comment: This should help: [useState source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L336)